# right aligning a bootstrap footer

Tags: html

I have a footer that is set up as follows:

```
    <hr>
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='Glossary.html'">Glossary</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='Bibliography.html'">Bibliography</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='For_Help.html'">Where To Go For Help</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6" style="padding-top: 5px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body col-xl-1">
                    <p> For questions or concerns regarding this webpage, contact: <strong>checkeredflags@gmail.com</strong></p>
                    <p>© 2017 <a href="index.html">Checkered Flags</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

How could I set it up such that the buttons are on the left, and the 2 paragraph tags are aligned with the buttons, however pulled to the right side of the screen? Currently the div with the paragraphs sits underneath the buttons. Ideally they would only go underneath when the screen size was small enough

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<div class="panel-body col-xl-1">
   <div class="pull-right">
      <p> For questions or concerns regarding this webpage, contact: 
      <strong>checkeredflags@gmail.com</strong></p>
      <p>© 2017 <a href="index.html">Checkered Flags</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that didn't quite do it. It aligns the text in a weird way and removes the box around it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `col-md-offset-6` class is pushing it down as well as the `padding-top: 5px;`.

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJaJwe

Comment: Agreed. The column offset is the main issue there.